# Python: how to include data files in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable of a project with the following structure

```
/projectdir
    project.spec
    /src
        /project
            main.py
            /submodule1
                 f1.py
            /res
                 f2.csv
```

Inside of `f1.py` there is a call to read `f2.csv` with the form `open('src/project/res/f2.csv')`. When I package it with `build` and install it somewhere else, it works without problems. However, I'm not able to create a working executable with `pyinstaller` (`pyinstaller -F project.spec`).

I've tried adding the file with `datas` inside of `project.spec`, as explained in the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) of `pyinstaller`:

```
 a = Analysis(['src/project/main.py'],
             pathex=[os.getcwd()+'/venv/lib/python3.8/',
                     os.getcwd()+'/src/'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./src/project/res/f2.csv',
                     '/src/project/res/')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['tkinter'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

However, when I execute the generated executable with `pyinstaller` I get an file not found error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/project/res/f2.csv'
```

What is the correct syntax to access this file? Should I change something in the `*.spec` file or should the call from `f1.py` be changed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with pyinstaller. I used a workaround hack that worked for me for image and .mo files. I created a script that turned the data files into base64. This same script then wrote out another python file containing the base64. This file was then packaged with pyinstaller. You can then write the file out for use in your software.
Example below shows both the creator file and the output file. At the end of the main.py file (in the qualcoder folder), I write the data files back out to be used.

https://github.com/ccbogel/QualCoder/tree/master/qualcoder/locale

Comment: This sounds similar to the qt resources (`*.qrc`), which are packaged with `pyrcc` and then imported from a `*.py` file. It's a valid idea, but I hope there is an easier way...